# GridView does not subscribe to CollectionChanged event

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, mvvm, windows-runtime

I have a custom list which looks like this:

```
public class MyCollection :   ICollection<Model>, 
                              ISupportIncrementalLoading, 
                              INotifyCollectionChanged, 
                              INotifyPropertyChanged
```

It raises the `CollectionChanged` event whenever I want to view to be updated, for instance:

```
public void Clear()
{
     InternalData.Clear();
     if (CollectionChanged != null)
     {
          CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
     }
}
```

I have a `GridView` whose property `ItemsSource` is bound to my custom collection. However, while I do have data in my custom collection (and I can browse this data with the Dynamic View field thanks to my custom `IEnumerator<Model> GetEnumerator()`), the event `CollectionChanged` is never fired because it is always `null`. It's like the `GridView` does not subscribe to the event. I don't know what can I do to force the GridView to listen to this event.

I have put a working sample on pastebin here : http://pastebin.com/01zS6yjP
The `CollectionChanged` event is always `null` event when the `GridView` is bound to the collection.

Comment: Most use `GridView` in combination with a `ListView`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752213(v=vs.100).aspx for instance.

Comment: Have you tried having your custom collection extend `ObservableCollection`? Or tested the same instance with the `ObservableCollection`? Also, try raising `PropertyChanged` on the property that the `GridView` is binding to (often "Items[]").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GridView` does not respond to the `CollectionChanged` event but to the `VectorChanged` event (implemented from `ObservableVector`).

Comment: I implemented IObservableVector, but VectorChanged is always null too